# How to call kartik gridview REFRESH function inside ajax success function

Tags: ajax, yii2

I want to refresh the kartik gridview in an ajax success function so that I can see the changes I made after a  successful UPDATE, but I don't know how to call the refresh function in kartik gridview in order to reflect the updates.

```
 $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url:'',
         dataType: 'html',
         data: {key:keys}, 
              success: function(data){
                       $.pjax.reload({container:'#pjax_id'});
           },                     
         });
```

Below is the Kartik Gridview

```
 echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' =>  $gridColumns,
    'containerOptions'=>['style'=>'overflow: auto'], 
    'headerRowOptions'=>['class'=>'kartik-sheet-style'],
    'filterRowOptions'=>['class'=>'kartik-sheet-style'],
    'id' =>'dempcc_grid_id',
    **'pjax'=>true, // pjax is set to always true for this demo
    'pjaxSettings' =>[
        'neverTimeout'=>true,
        'options'=>[
                'id'=>'pjax_id',
            ]
        ],**  
    'toolbar'=> [
     ['content'=>
       Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></i> Refresh', [''], ['data-pjax'=>1, 'class'=>'btn btn-default', 'title'=>'Reset Grid','id'=>'refresh'])

     ],
        '{export}',
        '{toggleData}',
        ],
    'panel'=>[
        'type'=>GridView::TYPE_PRIMARY,
        'heading'=>'REMITTANCE - DEMPCC',
    ],
      'persistResize'=>false,
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::begin(); ?>
<?= GridView::widget([
// ... configuration here
]);
<?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::end(); ?>
```

And update:
$.pjax.reload({container:'#idofyourpjaxwidget'});

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/655/how-to-use-gridview-with-ajax/